# Is it possible to sort Array Value with Array Value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an example like this:

```
code | name
a    | Pencil
b    | Pen
d    | Ruler
g    | TipeX
```

-

```
no | data  | list_order
1  | b,d,a | 2,3,1
2  | g,b,a | 3,2,1
```

So when run the query the data will be like this:

```
no | data | list_order
1  | b    | 2
1  | d    | 3
1  | a    | 1
```

Then I can sort it by list_order ASC

```
no | data | list_order
1  | a    | 1
1  | b    | 2
1  | d    | 3
```

My question, is it possible to get the query like above?

*I'm using Oracle DB

```
$q_data = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM DATAS WHERE NO = '1'");
oci_execute($q_data);
$row = oci_fetch_array($q_data);
$cp_array = implode(",",array($row['data']));
$cp_list_order = implode(",",array($row['list_order']));

$q_data_cp = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM DATAS_DTL WHERE no IN ($cp_array)");
oci_execute($q_data_cp);
while($d_data = oci_fetch_array($q_data_cp))
{
     $d_no = $d_data['no'];
     $d_name = $d_data['name'];
     ?>

     <div><?php echo $d_name; ?></div>

<?php
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use oracle db, but I use sql server and I think they both are similar in a lot of ways.

Try to do the following:

- create a temp table
- split the string using some kind of CROSS APPLY (see: [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns))
- insert the splitted values inside the temp table
- query the temp table

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the sample code, please have a look on that. Thanks